# UWP processing webcam image as Stream object

Tags: c#, uwp, stream, webcam, face-api

I am trying to process webcam image to detect faces on it with Microsoft Azure Face API.
Since the API accepts image url or stream, I need to get Stream objects of the MediaFrameReader, but I am unsuccessful in it.

I hope someone can solve this problem to me.

In many tries I got various kind of errors, for example:

Exception thrown at 0x7B8ADBAE (coreclr.dll) in FaceAPI.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x18670000.

Even BadRequest exception happened sometimes:

Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face.Models.APIErrorException: 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest''

You can see my code below:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face.Models;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Media.Capture;
using Windows.Media.Capture.Frames;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.AccessCache;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

namespace FaceAPI
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public FaceAPI Api { get; set; }

        private MediaCapture mediaCapture;
        private MediaFrameReader mediaFrameReader;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Api = new FaceAPI();
            await Setup();
        }

        private void btnDetect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SolidColorBrush fill_Brush = rectRecord.Fill as SolidColorBrush;

            if (fill_Brush.Color.R > 0)
            {
                rectRecord.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black);
                StopDetection();
            }
            else
            {
                rectRecord.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
                StartDetection();
            }
        }

        private async void btnSetFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FolderPicker picker = new FolderPicker();
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
            picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
            picker.CommitButtonText = "This Folder";
            StorageFolder objPicked_Folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

            if (objPicked_Folder != null)
            {
                string sPath = objPicked_Folder.Path;
                StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(objPicked_Folder, "metadata");
                tbxFolder.Text = sPath;
                Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["Folder_to_Save"] = sPath;
            }
        }

        private async void btnOpenFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            String sPath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["Folder_to_Save"] as string;
            StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(sPath);
            await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFolderAsync(folder);
        }

        private async Task Setup()
        { 
            await InitCapture();
            InitCamera();
            string folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["Folder_to_Save"] as string;
            tbxFolder.Text = folder;
        }

        private async Task InitCapture()
        {
            mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

            (App.Current as App).MediaCapture = mediaCapture;

            MediaCaptureInitializationSettings mediaCaptureInitSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings()
            {
                StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video
            };

            await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(mediaCaptureInitSettings);
            mediaCapture.Failed += MediaCaptureOnFailed;
            mediaCapture.RecordLimitationExceeded += MediaCaptureOnRecordLimitationExceeded;
        }

        private async void StartDetection()
        {
            var frameSourceGroups = await MediaFrameSourceGroup.FindAllAsync();

            MediaFrameSourceGroup selectedGroup = null;
            MediaFrameSourceInfo colorSourceInfo = null;

            foreach (var sourceGroup in frameSourceGroups)
            {
                foreach (var sourceInfo in sourceGroup.SourceInfos)
                {
                    if (sourceInfo.MediaStreamType == MediaStreamType.VideoRecord
                        && sourceInfo.SourceKind == MediaFrameSourceKind.Color)
                    {
                        colorSourceInfo = sourceInfo;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (colorSourceInfo != null)
                {
                    selectedGroup = sourceGroup;
                    break;
                }
            }         

            var allGroups = await MediaFrameSourceGroup.FindAllAsync();
            var eligibleGroups = allGroups.Select(g => new
            {
                Group = g,

                SourceInfos = new MediaFrameSourceInfo[]
                {
                    g.SourceInfos.FirstOrDefault(info => info.SourceKind == MediaFrameSourceKind.Color)
                }
            }).Where(g => g.SourceInfos.Any(info => info != null)).ToList();

            if (eligibleGroups.Count == 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No source group with color, depth or infrared found.");
                return;
            }

            var selectedGroupIndex = 0;
            selectedGroup = eligibleGroups[selectedGroupIndex].Group;
            colorSourceInfo = eligibleGroups[selectedGroupIndex].SourceInfos[0];

            var colorFrameSource = mediaCapture.FrameSources[colorSourceInfo.Id];

            var preferredFormat = colorFrameSource.SupportedFormats.Where(format =>
            {
                return format.VideoFormat.Width >= 1080
                && format.Subtype == "NV12";
            }).FirstOrDefault();

            if (preferredFormat == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            await colorFrameSource.SetFormatAsync(preferredFormat);

            mediaFrameReader = await mediaCapture.CreateFrameReaderAsync(colorFrameSource, "NV12");
            mediaFrameReader.AcquisitionMode = MediaFrameReaderAcquisitionMode.Buffered;
            mediaFrameReader.FrameArrived += CheckFrameForFaces;
            await mediaFrameReader.StartAsync();
        }

        private async void CheckFrameForFaces(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args)
        {
            var mediaFrame = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame();
            Stream image = mediaFrame?.VideoMediaFrame.FrameReference.BufferMediaFrame.Buffer.AsStream();

            if (image != null)
            {
                foreach (DetectedFace face in await Api.DetectFaces(image))
                {
                    //This is a test line so that I can put breakpoint to somewhere to be sure that the API processed the image
                    var age = face.FaceAttributes.Age;
                }
            }
        }

        private async void StopDetection()
        {
            await mediaFrameReader.StopAsync();
            mediaFrameReader.FrameArrived -= CheckFrameForFaces;
            mediaFrameReader.Dispose();
        }

        private async void InitCamera()
        {
            ctlCamera.Source = mediaCapture;
            await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
        }

        private async void MediaCaptureOnFailed(MediaCapture sender, MediaCaptureFailedEventArgs erroreventargs)
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                var warningMessage = new MessageDialog(String.Format("The video capture failed: {0}", erroreventargs.Message), "Capture Failed");
                await warningMessage.ShowAsync();
            });
        }

        private async void MediaCaptureOnRecordLimitationExceeded(MediaCapture sender)
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                await mediaCapture.StopRecordAsync();
                var warningMessage = new MessageDialog(String.Format("The video capture has exceeded its maximum length: {0}", "Capture Halted"));
                await warningMessage.ShowAsync();
            });
        }

        private async void FlSysMessagebox(string Text, string Title)
        {
            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(Text, Title);
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }

        private async Task UpdateStatus(string status)
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => Status.Text = status);
        }
    }
}
```

I can assure you that the Face API endpoint works, I tested it with image urls, but I want it to work with Stream to be able to process webcam image.

I tried a differnt way as well:

I tested if I can save the canvas image to a file using FileSavePicker and it worked, so I suppose I get a valid pixel buffer from this code:

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () => {
                RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
                await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(canvas);
                var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
                Stream img = pixelBuffer.AsStream();

                foreach (DetectedFace face in await Api.DetectFaces(img))
                {
                    var age = face.FaceAttributes.Age;
                }
            });
```

But the Stream that I got by calling AsStream() on pixelBuffer don't work with the Face API.

Comment: I'm afraid, you could not call face api in  `FrameArrived` event, because it will  get more frame for each second, then call face api post the steam to the Azure server.  But this api could not detect face for real time.  For your requirement we suggest you use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/detect-and-track-faces-in-an-image#track-faces-in-a-sequence-of-frames) to detect fame for frame.

Comment: Oh, you are right. But the original problem still occurrs, so I cannot create a Stream object of my webcam image. I am able to open a FileSavePicker and save it to the computer, but I don't want to interrupt the application with such interaction.

Comment: Please check [`CameraFaceDetection`](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraFaceDetection) code sample that suit your scenario.